# Please help me fix this javascript tool

Tags: javascript

This is in the head :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> f
function TextDefine(val) { 
    var i= 0;
    var array1 = val.value.split("\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i) { 
          array1[i] = "[b]" + array1[i] + "[/b]"; 
    }
    document.getElementById('another').value = array1.join("\n");
} 
</script>
```

Then This is in the body:

```
<textarea name="data" id="data"></textarea> 
<textarea name="another" id="another"></textarea> 
<input type="button" name="submit1" value="Submit" 
       onclick="TextDefine(document.getElementById('data'))" />
```

i would like to add another text area so that when i click on the generate button, it will also get the content of the text area i just created. example:

text area 1

```
content of the text area 1
```

text area i just created

```
content of the text area 2
```

then the generated content content in the thrid text area should be:

```
[b]content of the text area 1[/b]
content of the text area 2
```

please see the javascript code why it had [b], i do not know how do to it so i need your help :( Thank You!

Comment: What exactlyis the problem that you're having? You want the second text area to be automatically generated?

Comment: i want the content of the second text area get automatically generated together with the first when i click on the generate button

Answer (score 0):

Is the keyword function being split onto two words something to do with entering it into stackoverflow? The below works for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> function TextDefine(val){ var i= 0; var array1 = val.value.split("\n"); for ( i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i) { array1[i] = " [b]" + array1[i] + "[/b]"; } document.getElementById('another').value = array1.join("\n"); }</script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
<textarea name="data" id="data"></textarea> 
<textarea name="another" id="another"></textarea> 
<input type="button" name="submit1" value="Submit" onclick="TextDefine(document.getElementById('data'))" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                        function TextDefine(val, anotherval){
    var i= 0;                
var array1 = val.value.split("\n");
for ( i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i) {
    array1[i] = "[b]" + array1[i] + "[/b]";
}
document.getElementById('generate').value = array1.join("\n")+"\n"+ document.getElementById('another').value;

                        }
                        </script>
<textarea name="data" id="data"></textarea>
<textarea name="another" id="another"></textarea>
<textarea name="generate" id="generate"></textarea>
<input type="button" name="submit1" value="Submit" onclick="TextDefine(document.getElementById('data'), document.getElementById('another'))" />
```

Comment: nope, there should be three text areas all in all.. see first post again.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do?

http://jsbin.com/eligo4/edit